# SSBO unique buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer

I'm trying to create a set of SSBO (One per object instance) but they are all linked due to the line :

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, m_ssbo);
```

Is there a way to make a SSBO incremental to prevent multiples instances to access the same buffer ?

My SSBO code :

```
// SSBO
glGenBuffers(1, &m_ssbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, m_ssbo);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(m_blocks), m_blocks, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, m_ssbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying the problem is?

Comment: Imagine I have 2 entities. They both have a SSBO, but they also both indicate the same buffer Id (0). If one modify buffer data, the second one will be affected too. Is there a way to associate a unique buffer to each entities ? Like an incremental ID in a MySQL table :)

Comment: Are you calling `glGenBuffers(1, &m_ssbo);` once per entity, or just once?

Comment: Once per entity

Comment: And when you render each entity are you binding that entity's buffer?

Comment: I guess it is linked to my VAO, or am I just too dumb ? x)

Comment: Seems that wasn't the solution, my entities still sharing the data.

Comment: Nothing in OpenGL prevents you from having one buffer per entity. You don't have to do anything special to have one buffer per entity, other than using a different buffer for each different entity. So it sounds like you have a bug in your program, which can't be solved with the information you've provided.

Comment: The problem get solved by rebinding properly my SSBO, and rebuilding my whole solution. Thanks for helping !